# Pandas: Close-to-Open return on stocks

Tags: returns, python

I am trying to daily calculate the close-to-open return for j stocks for t days. Is there anyway I can calculate without using a for loop? I have one Dataframe for daily close prices and one for daily open. I am using python.

If it is close-to-close return, I am able to use the pct_change, not sure for close-to-open.

```
RCO(t,j) = SO(t,j)/SC(t-1,j)-1
```

where RCO is the returns on day t for stock j, SO is the opening price and SC is the previous days closing price.

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to this code example, which calculates open-to-close returns over the past five trading days.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
symbol = 'WIKI/AAPL'
df = web.DataReader(symbol, 'quandl', '2018-01-01', '2018-03-31')
df['AdjClose'] / df['AdjOpen'].shift(5) - 1  # change 5 to the desired interval
```

Comment: thanks, but that still means I have to run one loop for j number of stocks right?

Comment: @Prash It depends on how you construct the inputs. If you have one `DataFrame` for closing prices and one `DataFrame` for opening quotes with matching columns names, you can divide the two (with appropriate `shift`s) directly. You can also play around with higher dimensional data structures like `xarray`.